# Posting an aggregation as a new document/collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

In my client I have a form that is sent and stored in Mongo. Made an aggregation to get the name of the people that selected a same place, date and time. Now I would like to create a Mongo document containing all matches as collections so whenever there is a match in place, date and time of people you can get it in a collection. This is what I have so far:

```
router.get('/match', async (req, res) => {
    const matchs = await Forms.aggregate([
      { 
        $group: {
          _id: { Date: "$date", Time: "$time", Place: "$place" }, 
          Data: { $addToSet: {Name: "$firstName", Surname:"$surname"}},
          count: { $sum: 1 }
        } 
      }, 
      { 
        $match: { 
          count: { $gte: 2} 
        } 
      },
    ]);
    res.json(matchs)
});
```

This is the result that I would like to store in Mongo:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "Date": "2022-04-20",
    "Time": "15:00",
    "Place": "Mall"
  },
  "Data": [
    {
      "Name": "Carl",
      "Surname": "Man"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Christian",
      "Surname": "Max"
    }
  ],
  "count": 2
}
```

```
{
  "_id": {
    "Date": "2022-04-20",
    "Time": "13:00",
    "Place": "Restaurant"
  },
  "Data": [
    {
      "Name": "Felix",
      "Surname": "Sad"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Liu",
      "Surname": "Lam"
    }
  ],
  "count": 2
}
```

Comment: The output of an aggregate can be written to another collection, using the `$out` stage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$out` as the last stage in your pipeline. In the following example, `matching_collection` will contain the result of your pipeline.

```
{ $out : "matching_collection" }
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

You can also check `$merge`, it could be helpful as well.